# TYPE_USE annotations with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a rather exotic use-case that I have to support. Types annotated with `@Id` need custom deserialization logic, e.g. the value should be Base64 decoded before deserializing it (not the only case).

Since the behavior is applicable to any annotated type anywhere (e.g. `List<@Id Key>`), I reckon I need a custom `TypeAdapterFactory`, but the problem is that `TypeAdapterFactory#create` only gives access to `TypeToken` (thus `Type`, not `AnnotatedType`).

```
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    if (type.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) //not possible :( {
        ... //custom logic here
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So it seem there's no way to make a decision based on an annotation inside the custom deserializer. Or is there an approach I'm missing?

I found out the Immutables project has [a fixture](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/master/value-fixture/src/org/immutables/fixture/HasTypeAnnotation.java) that tests whether type annotations are correctly preserved when they generate the `TypeAdapterFactory`, or so it seems at least... That gives me hope there's a way around this.

Comment: Do you mean that you have for example something like `@Entity public class MyEntity { @Id private Long id; }` to deserialize? But the type of `id` can vary depending on the `Entity`?

Comment: @pirho That would be a fair explanation, yes. The common thing is that everything annotated by `@Id` is e.g. Base64 encoded, so the deserialization logic needs to be customized to first decode. And since it's a TYPE_USE annotation, it could also be something like `List<@Id Key>`.